# ES6 Javascript for appending child to the function caller/invoker

Tags: javascript, html, function, ecmascript-6, appendchild

I googled and checked almost all the posts for finding some reference on how to append child/node to function-caller or function-invoker parent node, but in vain, as I didn't find any single article that sheds any light on it.

I have already tried below code but it throws the error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.appendChild is not a function`:

```html
<button class="class1 class2 class3" onclick="addSubNode(this)">Add Node</button>
<script type="application/javascript">
function addSubNode() {
let subNode = document.createElement('span');
subNode.classList.add('class1');
subNode.innerText = 'TestSpan';
// this.classList
this.appendChild(subNode);
}
</script>
```

If I try to fetch it's classList(commented line) then also it says `this.classList is not a function`.

How do I achieve what I explained in the question ?

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/obL5jgyr/6/)

Comment: You would need an argument to represent `this`. There's no argument in `function addSubNode` when it's defined. Better yet, separate your JavaScript from HTML then you can just get the node and assign the Listener which will be call in the `this` context. Inline EventListeners are like Anonymous functions. So, I would do something like `const butt = document.querySelector('button'); butt.onclick = addSubNode;`.

Answer (score 1):

```html
    <button class="class1 class2 class3" onclick="addSubNode(this)">Add Node</button>
    <script type="application/javascript">
    function addSubNode(that) {
        let subNode = document.createElement('span');
        subNode.classList.add('class1');
        subNode.innerText = 'TestSpan';
        // this.classList
        that.appendChild(subNode);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Will this one work with `async` methods as well, I just tried this approach, but it gave me error: `Cannot read property appendChild of null`

Comment: `that.appendChild(subNode);` is not `this.appendChild(subNode);`. OP probably didn't see that. Events are Asynchronous.